# Find all homomorphisms $Q \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_8$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $Q$ be the quaternion group. Find all homomorphisms $\phi: Q \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_8$

What I get into is one big ifology:

> Of course $\phi(1) = 0$, then $0 = \phi(1) = \phi(-1 \cdot (-1)) = 2 \phi (-1)$, so $\phi(-1) = 0 \lor \phi(-1) = 4$. If $\phi(-1) = 0$, then $ 0 = \phi(i^2) = 2\phi(i)$, so  $\phi(i) = 0 \lor \phi(i) = 4$, and so on... Ad afterwards, check whether everything found is a homomorphism indeed.

Can one do this in a more clever manner? This is something like $2^4$ cases to check!

Comment: Actually it's easy to prove $\ \phi(-1) = 4 $ is impossible. Use the relation $\ ijk= -1 $ So atleast case is reduced to $\ 2^{3}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following fact. Of course, you should prove it first before using it (unless done in class).

> If $f:G\to A$ is a homomorphism of groups, and $A$ is abelian, then for all $x,y\in G$ their *commutator* $[x,y]=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ is mapped to the neutral element of $A$.

Then I strongly advice you to compute $[i,j]$ in $Q$. This results in a significant reduction in ifology. Particularly if you recall that $uv=\pm w$ where $\{u,v,w\}$ are the quaternions $i,j,k$ in some order.

Answer (score 1):

Such a homomorphism is the same as a cyclic quotient of $Q$.

Answer (score 1):

This should kill most cases:

Observe that $kji = 1$, so

$$ 0 = \phi(1) = \phi(kji) = \phi(k)+\phi(j)+\phi(i) = \phi(ijk) = \phi(-1) $$

and hence $\phi(i), \phi(j), \phi(k)$ all have order $2$.